# Use RxJs to empty a queue

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to empty a queue/buffer of unknown length that is limited by an empty string.

Example: `in->["","P2","P1"]->out`

There is a call that returns the next element in the queue. `function getNext():Observable<string>` This Observable is cold and short-lived. So the only thing that i could do is:

```
getNext().subscribe(console.log,console.err,()=>console.log("complete"));
--> "P1"
--> "complete"
getNext().subscribe(console.log,console.err,()=>console.log("complete"));
--> "P2"
--> "complete"
getNext().subscribe(console.log,console.err,()=>console.log("complete"));
--> ""
--> "complete"
```

I would like to turn it into a semi-short-lived observable that emitts values until the empty string is emitted and then completes.

```
theBetterGetNext().subscribe(console.log,console.err,()=>console.log("complete"));
--> "P1"
--> "P2"
--> ""
--> "complete"
```

For a fixed length that would be easy. `of(1,2,3).pipe(mergeMap(()=>getNext()))` but I am struggeling with the unknown length. Could you please guide me to a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `repeatWhen` is your operator:

```js
const theBetterGetNext = () => getNext().pipe(
  repeatWhen(value => value === "" ? EMPTY : of(null))
);

theBetterGetNext().subscribe(
  console.log,
  console.error,
  () => console.log("complete")
);
```

This should resubscribe to the source until the value is empty (=== "")

**Edit**: I'm making an assumption here: You don't need to call `getNext` again to get a new value, but you can reuse the initial observable...

I just found another solution if you need to call `getNext()`:

```js
const theBetterGetNext = () => getNext().pipe(
  expand(value => value === "" ? EMPTY : getNext())
);

theBetterGetNext().subscribe(
  console.log,
  console.error,
  () => console.log("complete")
);
```

Comment: Nice, not OP, but expand is a great fit for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `takeWhile` operator to take values only while they are not an empty string.

Once you get an empty string, the observable will complete:

```js
of(1, 2, 3)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(() => getNext()),
    takeWhile(val => val !== "")
  )
  .subscribe(
    console.log,
    console.error,
    () => console.log("complete")
  );
```

Comment: looks like, what i want, but the way you did it there is a maximum of three operations, right? Because of: of(1,2,3). I might use interval() to emit an infinite amount of read opperations, but i don't want to wait, during the read opperations. Is there something more appropriate then, interval()?

Comment: ok, I was going by your example using `mergeMap`. If you need to continually call `getNext` then `expand` is probably your best bet, as suggested by olivarra1.